# PHP require_once fails?

Tags: php

So, I'm trying to build a template-loader system with PHP. Here's what I got so far:

config.php:

```
<?php
    $style_assets_path = "/includes/styles/";

    if ($_GET['page_id'] !== '1'){
        header('Location: /template.php?pageid=1');
        exit(0);
    }

    if ($_GET['page_id'] <= 100) {
        $template = "/main/main.php";
    }

    function loadTemplate() {
        require_once dirname(__FILE__) . "$style_assets_path" . "templates" . "$template";
        // This should output: /includes/styles/templates/main/main.php
    }
?>
```

home.php:

```
<?php
    require_once dirname(__FILE__) . "/config.php";
    loadTemplate($template);
?>
```

So I get the following error when I open home.php:

`Warning: require_once(/home/xxxxxxx/public_htmltemplates/) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory...`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your path is just wrong, try it in a browser.

Comment: Pay attention to the `require_once` thing it's showing you. `public_htmltemplates` probably isn't right!

Comment: shouldn't it be public_html/templates?

Comment: remove the dbl quotes from `"$style_assets_path"` like `$style_assets_path`. And `"$template"` as well

Comment: Also, everything should be in parens. Try this: require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . "/config.php");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HERE CORRECT ANSWER !!!!!
Look carefully at your ERROR MESSAGE!
that's because, that **$style_assets_path** is not determined in function.
you should make those variables **global** in function:

```
 function loadTemplate() {
        global $style_assets_path;
        global $template;
        require_once dirname(__FILE__) . "$style_assets_path" . "templates" . "$template";
        // This should output: /includes/styles/templates/main/main.php
    }
```

Comment: `$template` would still be out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

Functions are in different scope to your global variables, you can't access them unless you either pass them in as arguments or use the global keyword(mentioned only for completeness).

If your values aren't going to change though declare them as constants, much prettier:

```
declare('STYLE_ASSETS_PATH', "/includes/styles/");

if ($_GET['page_id'] !== '1'){
    header('Location: /template.php?pageid=1');
    exit(0);
}

if ($_GET['page_id'] <= 100) {
    $template = "/main/main.php";
}

loadTemplate($template);

function loadTemplate($template) {
    require_once dirname(__FILE__) . STYLE_ASSETS_PATH . "templates" . "$template";
}
```